# Distribution of $\int_0^t \left(\int_0^s W(u)\,du\right)\,ds$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am considering the following Stochastic dynamics:
$$
\mathrm d\mathbf x(t) = \mathbf F\,\mathbf x(t) \mathrm dt + \mathbf L\,\mathrm d\mathbf W(t), \quad \mathbf x(0) = \mathbf x_0
$$
where $\mathbf x(t) = [x(t), v(t), a(t)]^\top,$ $\mathbf W(t) = [W_x(t), W_v(t), W_a(t)]^\top$ is a vector of independent Wiener processes and
$$
\mathbf F=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
\mathbf L =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sigma_a
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

When trying to find the distribution of $x(t)$ I get two different values for the variance.

**REMARK: Notation $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ used for normal distributions with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.**

---

1. Integrating the equations recursively I get:
   $$
   x(t) = x(0) + v(0)t + a(0)\frac{t^2}{2} + \sigma_a\int_0^t\!\left(\int_0^s W_a(u)\mathrm du\right)\!\mathrm ds.
   $$

Using the Itô formula of integration-by-parts for the inner integral:
$$
\int_0^t\!\left(\int_0^s W_a(u)\mathrm du\right)\!\mathrm ds = \int_0^t\!\left(sW_a(s) - \int_0^s u\mathrm dW_a(u)\right)\!\mathrm ds,
$$
and doing the same for the first term obtained:
$$
\int_0^t sW_a(s)\mathrm ds = \frac{t^2}{2}W_a(t) - \int_0^t \frac{s^2}{2}\mathrm dW_a(s).
$$
Now we apply the following: [Why can I exchange the order of integration in a multiple Ito stochastic integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521497/why-can-i-exchange-the-order-of-integration-in-a-multiple-ito-stochastic-integra) to the second term to get:
$$
\int_0^t\!\left(\int_0^s u\mathrm dW_a(u)\right)\!\mathrm ds
= \int_0^t\!\left(\int_0^s u\mathrm du\right)\mathrm dW_a(s)
= \int_0^t\!\frac{s^2}{2}\mathrm dW_a(s).
$$

Gathering all these results:
$$
\int_0^t\!\left(\int_0^s W_a(u)\mathrm du\right)\!\mathrm ds = \frac{t^2}{2}W_a(t) - \int_0^t s^2\mathrm dW_a(s).
$$

It is known that $\int_0^t f(s)dW(s)\sim\mathcal N\!\left(0,\int_0^t f(s)^2\mathrm ds\right),$ if $f$ is differentiable. So,
$$
\int_0^t\!\left(\int_0^s W_a(u)\mathrm du\right)\!\mathrm ds\sim
\mathcal N\!\left(0,\frac{t^5}{4}\right) - \mathcal N\!\left(0,\frac{t^5}{5}\right) \sim \mathcal N\!\left(0,\frac{9}{20}t^5\right).
$$

---

2. On the other hand, since $\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf L$ are both constant, following Simo Särkkä and Arno Solin *Applied Stochastic Differential Equations* book:
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \mathbf x(t) &= \exp(\mathbf F(t))\mathbf x_0 + \int_{0}^t \exp(\mathbf F(t-s))\,\mathbf L\, \mathrm d\mathbf W(s)\\[5mm]
   & =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & t & \frac{t^2}{2}\\
   0 & 1 & t\\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
   \mathbf x_0
   +
   \int_{0}^t
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & \frac{(t-s)^2}{2}\sigma_a\\
   0 & 1 & (t-s)\sigma_a\\
   0 & 0 & \sigma_a
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathrm d W_x(s)\\
   \mathrm d W_v(s)\\
   \mathrm d W_a(s)
   \end{bmatrix}.
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   Thus,
   $$
   x(t) = \left[1, t, \frac{t^2}{2}\right]\mathbf x_0 \,+\sigma_a\int_{0}^t \frac{(t-s)^2}{2}dW_a(s).
   $$
   In this case, I get:
   $$
   \int_{0}^t \frac{(t-s)^2}{2}dW_a(s)\sim\mathcal N\!\left(0, \frac{t^5}{20}\right).
   $$

**WHERE'S THE MISTAKE?**

Comment: $\color{red}{\text{Don't shout.}}$ $\phantom{\quad}$ Does this answer your question? [Rewriting a stochastic integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467510/rewriting-a-stochastic-integral)

Comment: After receiving two full blown answers I guess it is time that you accept/upvote or ask further questions if necessary.

Comment: @Kurt G. I really appreciate your help, both for the first comment and for the subsequent answer.
However, I think you should take into account that people can't dedicate their whole day checking MathStackExchange updates, so please give them some time to review the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. I don't know where your mistake is but it follows
from the integration-by-parts formula that
$$
\textstyle\int_0^sW_u\,du=\int_0^s(s-u)\,dW_u\sim N(0,\frac{s^3}{3})\,\,.
$$
Then, using stochastic Fubini,
$$
\textstyle\int_0^t\int_0^sW_u\,du\,ds=\int_0^t\int_0^s(s-u)\,dW_u\,ds\stackrel{Fub}{=}\int_0^t\int_u^t(s-u)\,ds\,dW_u=\int_0^t\frac{(t-u)^2}{2}\,dW_u\sim N(0,\frac{t^5}{20})\,.
$$
Because the variance of the last integral is
$$
\textstyle\int_0^t\frac{(t-u)^4}{4}\,du\,.
$$